# How to set the maximal amount of authors and editors in my bibliography using babelbib?

Tags: bibliographies, author-number

I currently use `babelbib` with the `alphadin` style for my bibliography for my Bachelor thesis. Now I have to deal with a resource which has four authors and is an `@incollection` of a book having eight editors (publishers).

When I have a resource with more than three authors/editors, my thesis tutor wants me to mention the first three authors/editors only and append an `et al.` afterwards. I know that this is possible using `biblatex` but I'm using `babelbib`. I haven't found any setting or workaround to do this and the documentary doesn't help in any way. Is there any way to do this? I also checked the `alphadin.bst` style for doing this but there is no variable for the maximal amount of authors and editors neither.

If it is not possible: I use Citavi as my literature organizing software. Is there any way to archive that only three authors will be exported, followed by `and others` which LaTeX will replace by `et al.`? I haven't found an option for this, too.
I would favourize it to do this in latex.

**Edit**: This is the part where I include the bibliography package:

```
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{ngerman}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\refname}{Literatur- und Quellenverzeichnis}}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
```

Comment: I had the problem that I wasn't able to display the whole bibliography in German. There were always some English fragments in the bibliography, for example `p.` for page. I also had the problem that ISSNs and DOIs didn't show up at all for some document types such as `@misc`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I really have to use babelbib and have not a choice using another bibliography and there is no option by babelbib itself to define the maximum amount of authors, I decided to have a look how I may modify the `alphadin.bst` file.

I introduced two new variables:

`INTEGERS { et.al.char.used.names et.al.char.used.names.stop }`

where the first one counts the amount of authors of a given source and the second one indicates, whether an `et al.` was written yet or not.

One has to edit the function `format.names` for having only three names:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ #0 'et.al.char.used.names :=
  #0 'et.al.char.used.names.stop := 
  's :=
  "" 'u  :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    {
       s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ 't :=
       t capitalize 't :=
       s nameptr "{ jj}" format.name$ 'w :=
       s nameptr "{, ff}{ vv}{ jj}" format.name$ 'u :=
       u  text.length$  'lang :=
       #1 'zahl :=
       "" 'v :=
         {  zahl  lang  <  }
         {  u  zahl  #1  substring$  "~"  =
               {  v  ""  =
                     {  u  #1  zahl  #1  -  substring$  'v :=  }
                     'skip$
                  if$
                  v  u  zahl  #2  substring$ * "." *  w * 'v :=
                }
               'skip$
            if$
            zahl  #1  +  'zahl :=  }
      while$
      v  ""  =
         {  u  'v :=  }
         'skip$
      if$
      t  v  *  fkt  *  't :=
      nameptr #1 >
         {

         et.al.char.used.names #1 + 'et.al.char.used.names :=   

         namesleft #1 >
             { 

                et.al.char.used.names #2 >
                    { 
                        et.al.char.used.names.stop #1 =
                        {}
                        {
                            ua.etal *
                            #1 'et.al.char.used.names.stop :=
                        }
                        if$
                    }
                    { "; " * t * }
                if$
             }
           % { "; " * t * }
             { numnames #2 >
                  { "" * }
                  'skip$
               if$

               et.al.char.used.names.stop #1 =
                {}
                {
                   t "\textsc{others}" = t "\textsc{others} (Hrsg.)" =  or
                      { ua.etal * }
                      { 
                        et.al.char.used.names #2 >
                            { ua.etal * }
                            { "; " * t * }
                        if$
                      } 
                   if$
                }
                if$
               }
            if$  %% Ende der namesleft-Pruefung
          }
            't
           if$  %%  Ende der nameptr-Pruefung

      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 -  'namesleft :=
    }
  while$  %%  Ende von { namesleft #0 > } ganz oben
  "" 'fkt :=  %% fkt wird zurueckgesetzt
  #0 'et.al.char.used.names :=  %%% MODIFIZIERT 
  #0 'et.al.char.used.names.stop :=  %%% MODIFIZIERT 
}
```

and the function `format.lab.names` for the tokens (e.g. `[ABC12]`) to display only the initials of three authors instead of 5 before adding a `+`:

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames #1 >
    { numnames #3 >                     %% MODIFIZIERT war 4
        { #3 'namesleft := }
        { numnames 'namesleft := }
      if$
      #1 'nameptr :=
      ""
        { namesleft #0 > }
        { nameptr numnames =
            { s nameptr "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
%%                { "\," *  %% kein besonderes Zeichen fuer "others" i. label
                { "{\etalchar{+}}" *   %% ein plus-Zeichen (+) fuer "others"!
                  #1 'et.al.char.used :=
                }
                { s nameptr "{l{}}" format.name$ * }
              if$
            }
            { s nameptr "{l{}}" format.name$ * }
          if$
          nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
          namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
        }
      while$
      numnames #3 >                     %% MODIFIZIERT war 4
%%        { "\," *  %%  s. Bemerkung oben
        { "{\etalchar{+}}" *
          #1 'et.al.char.used :=
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    { s #1 "{l{}}" format.name$
      duplicate$ text.length$ #2 <
        { pop$ s #1 "{ll}" format.name$ #3 text.prefix$ } %%  vgl. Anmerkung!
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Maybe this helps someone if needed.